# How to display sidebar collapse content without overflow: visible?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using fixed left `.navbar` and want to show `.collapse` content when my `.navbar` toggled (stacked to left). I managed to do this, but when I want to scroll the `.navbar` while the .navbar is stacked to do this I have to set `.navbar` to `overflow: auto`. But when the `.navbar` is `.toggled`, if the overflow not set `visible` the menu `.collapse` not visible too. How can I make the `.navbar` scrollable and show the `.collapse` content together?

**Here is the picture for better understanding:**
[image]

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #152e4d;
    border-color: #12263f;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1030
}

.navbar.toggled {
    width: 6.5rem !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.navbar.toggled .nav-item .collapse {
    background-color: #152e4d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #102137;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    max-height: 22rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(6.5rem + 1.5rem / 2);
    z-index: 1;
    top: 2px;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark nav-left">

    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <i class="bi bi-currency-bitcoin"></i>
        <span>Brand</span>
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault" style="">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="">
                    <i class="bi bi-graph-up"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#collapse1" role="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
                    <i class="bi bi-box-seam"></i>
                    <span>Packages</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#navbarsExampleDefault">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a>                    
                </div>
            </li>           
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
        <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="mininavToggle"></button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Bootstrap 5. Why?

Comment: I forgot the remove `in` and `toggled` is my custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children of fixed position elements share the same stacking context as the parent so things like z-index and overflow are relative to the fixed parent. Therefore the Collapse sub-menus would also have to be fixed position.

I couldn't get your example to render properly in Bootstrap 5, but here's a working example: https://codeply.com/p/YoRN1YaPs0

The CSS would look something like..

```
.nav-item .collapsing {
    background-color: #152e4d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. But now i need to display `.collapse` content in proper position according to screen height.